# CloudKit predicate returning error with array[LAST]

Tags: arrays, swift, cloudkit

I am working on creating a CloudKit subscription predicate, and I need to use `array[LAST]` in the predicate. If I attempt to use this I get the following error:

```
Optional(<CKError 0x1c42446b0: "Invalid Arguments" (12/1009); "Expected key-path in comparison expression: SELF[LAST] == "username"">)
```

In the code below, by goal is to determine whether the last item in a list of strings is the same as a variable.

```
 let subscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "MessageConversation", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "SELF[LAST] = %@",  "username" as CVarArg), options: .firesOnRecordCreation)
```

What am I doing wrong that would product that error?

Comment: Are you sure that `self` is an array in this context?

Comment: @losiowaty I'm not certain. If I replace `SELF` with the name of a field that I know is certainly an array, the same error is produced.

Comment: Try self.lastObject. But it might be best to query all subscriptions once and save to a model and just check the model.

Comment: Sorry might even try self.last.  But i still think loading them all in a model during the uptime of the app would be best.

Comment: @agibson007 Thank you. I have considered loading everything, but I can expect that there may be a lot of records matching the query. I'l try using `self.lastObject`.

Comment: Explain again what you are trying to get. Are you just trying to subscribe to a conversation with the user.

Comment: I have a field that is an array of strings. I want to get the last user in that array which is the recipient in a conversation. I want to subscribe to new conversations in which a certain user is the recipient.